# bootstrap javascript events not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

None of the bootstrap javascript events (in this case, the ones for collapse / expand) will bind to my elements. I'm new to bootstrap, so probably there's an issue somewhere????

When pasted into bootply it works fine http://www.bootply.com/tMvXXUvlz6

limited edition live example of the broken version also available here http://quirell.ngrok.io/tagged/life#

head.html:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

body.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Lynn Cyrin</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/tagged/life">Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="/tagged/advocacy">Advocacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/tagged/tech">Tech</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

footer.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

---

EDITS:

There's nothing on the console that shows any error message. I just noticed that there's a line at the top of [bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) that throws an error is jQuery isn't present, and I can't get that line to trigger (by removing jQuery).

I had a feeling that all js was broken, so I did `console.log('pizza')` right below the call to bootstrap.js, and that worked fine. It's as if my page is never applying the contents of bootstrap.js ??????

Comment: do you mean everything is working as expected in bootply? if so, have you added all required references in your website. Please check the browser's error console.

Comment: The references are in the question beneath footer.html and head.html? And browser console is empty

Comment: Your example in bootply.com is running on jquery 1.9.1 and bootstrap 3.0.0. I'm not saying the versions you are using will not work. I'm saying you are comparing different versions.

Comment: @SherinMathew just tried it with `<script href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and still nothing

Comment: Hmm... i tried to create page in jsfiddle using the same references 2.1.4 jquery and 3.3.4 bootstrap. It works. http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/0b47cvvm/. So it is something specific to your page. Can you paste the whole html source in the question? the whole content rendered in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `src` on both `<script>` tags. You have `href` on the Bootstrap one.

Also, should probably ditch the `https` and just use `//<url here>` so that it works with whatever protocol you're requesting the site with.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Jquery link below the bootstrap. because in your case browser first load jQuery and then try to load bootstrap, which create conflict

Comment: Extra thing I just discovered, there's a part in bootstrap.js that says

    `if(!jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery");`

If I get rid of jQuery, I don't get this error in console